# Chef-client is unable to find repositories in local mode

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, cookbook

I am a beginner on chef and want to automate deployment process. To test a simple script, I have downloaded chefdk. I have created repositories, cookbooks and recipies. Now, I want to run a recipe, I am using the following command:

```
chef-client -z -r 'recipe[example::default]'
```

This command works fine whenever executed from inside the ../repository/ directory. However, when I try to execute it from outside that directory, it fails saying it is unable to find the cookbook.

From the documentation (which hasn't helped much, to be honest) I found that we can configure cookbook path in knife.rb file, but in my case, there is no such file (as I am just trying to run chef client locally). Is there any other way to pass cookbook path at runtime, along with chef-client command?

Answer (score 0):

1. Chef can find cookbook repository automatically - if you will run your command from cookbook directory
2. If you dont want to enter this directory every time, you can change your `COOKBOOK_PATH` setting inside config file. If you don't have this file, you will have to create it and run command:

   `chef-client --local -c PATH_TO_FILE`

   List of setting that can be changed there you can find [HERE](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html). The most important for you are `chef_repo_path` and `cookbook_path`.

Hope this helps :)